# Pass jquery - generated variable to php in same page

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have a script that gets tha data on the row of a button when that button is clicked. The id of the button is id='show-button'. This is the script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".show-button").click(function() {
             var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
             var names = $row.find(".name").text(); // Find the name
             var surname = $row.find(".surname").text(); // Find the surname 
             var lecturer_id = names."_".surname;
             $("#show_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
             $(".show-button").on("click", function() {$("#show_dialog").dialog("open");});
         });
        });
    </script>
```

The last two significant lines open a jquery dialog box. 
With that, i mean  these lines:

```
$("#show_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
$(".show-button").on("click", function() {$("#show_dialog").dialog("open");});
```

Now, I need to pass the value of var lecturer_id to a php script outside this code, but inside the same document. This php code will generate the content of the dialog crated by these two lines. Lets assume that I just want to echo the variable passed inside the dialog box (with the php).

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX. No matter what the PHP will run on the server-side so you will not be accessing the already rendered page though.

Comment: I figured that much out. But I dont know how to do it. ajax post seems to pass data on other files. I need to pass it within the last two lines that make the call for the dialogbox

Comment: Is this something that PHP has already rendered and you just need to access it?

Comment: No, it's not. I use jquery to get the the data in the same row as the button (name and surname). Now lets assume that I want to create a dialog box with $("#show_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
$(".show-button").on("click", function() {$("#show_dialog").dialog("open");});                            In this dialogbox I want to echo the name and surname.

Comment: You would then just use the info from the JS variables to display the name and surname. No need for AJAX or PHP in this case. `$('#show_dialog').html(name + ' ' + surname);` if `#show_dialog` is the id of the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, but, just an idea, if I got you right:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(".show-button").click(function() {
         var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
         var names = $row.find(".name").text(); // Find the name
         var surname = $row.find(".surname").text(); // Find the surname 
         var lecturer_id = names."_".surname;
        $.post( "test.php", { names: names, surname: surname; lecturer_id: lecturer_id })
            .done(function( data ) {
            $("#show_dialog")[0].innerHTML = data ;
            $("#show_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
            $(".show-button").on("click", function() {$("#show_dialog").dialog("open");});
        });

    });
});
    </script>
```

And I agree with @JayBlanchard you don't even need any ajax call here, just generate your html like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".show-button").click(function() {
             var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
             var names = $row.find(".name").text(); // Find the name
             var surname = $row.find(".surname").text(); // Find the surname 
             var lecturer_id = names."_".surname;

            $("#show_dialog")[0].innerHTML = ' Name = '+names +'; Surname = '+surname ;
                $("#show_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
                $(".show-button").on("click", function() {$("#show_dialog").dialog("open");});


        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery post or ajax.

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

`test.php` will be the reciving end of php, where it expects data sent by jquery.
`{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }` will be the data you are wishing to send off to php.
`data` will be the the data output by php.

refer to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more information

Comment: what do you want to do..? the question didn't say you didnt want to do ajax call.

Comment: Ok, to clarify it. The data that I take with jquery, I simply want to post it. With php. Inside the dialog box that I create inside the jquery. It should be something like this : <?php
      
      echo '<div id="show_dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">';
      echo $jquery_data;   
      echo '</div>';
 
  ?>

Comment: so simply inject that post call inside your dialog box. if you are not waiting for a response, then you don't need to use that data returned by the post call.

Comment: but the dialog box is created inside the jquery. And I cannot write php inside it (cant write jquery inside php)